ajax request failing with "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'open')"
Feel like I'm missing something obvious (I don't work with javascript or jQuery, I'm just playing around with it in my spare time), but I can't figure out why my ajax request won't work - can't find the answer anywhere on google either.
When I try an ajax request with the below code, it fails with the error: ajax request failing with "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'open')" - it doesn't even hit my api endpoint
$.ajax({
        url: window.location.origin + "/api/test",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json"
    })
        .done(function (json) {
            conole.log(json);
        })
        .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
        });

If I do it with vanilla javascript, it works fine:
var r = await fetch(window.location.origin + "/api/test", {
        method: "GET"
    });

I've tried messing around with all kinds of properties in the ajax request, but to no avail. What am I missing?

I suspect this is the xhr.open() call internal to $.ajax(). But the only way xhr could be undefined is if there's an error calling new window.XMLHttpRequest() to create the XHR object.

Is it possible you've redefined XMLHttpRequest somewhere in your code?

Not in my code - this is the only javascript code I have written - it it part of an asp net core app though - which has other libraries used by the page. Do you think they could be interfering?

I would be surprised if jQuery were incompatible with ASP.Net. They're both too popular to not work together.

If you put console.log(XMLHttpRequest) before the AJAX call, what does it show?

It may just be a typo/copy-paste error, but in your .done you have conole.log instead of console.log.

@CarenRose - good spot, but was just a copy/paste error, the done function never gets hit.

@Barmar
ƒ XMLHttpRequest() { [native code] }
DONE: 4
HEADERS_RECEIVED : 2
LOADING: 3
OPENED: 1:
UNSENT: 0
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 0
name: "XMLHttpRequest"

That looks like the standard value, so I can't think of any reason why xhr would be undefined.
